# How to move rows in excel based on a formula

Tags: excel

I tried to look at moving and selecting items in Excel in the documentation over [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-or-copy-a-formula-1f5cf825-9b07-41b1-8719-bf88b07450c6) and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Select-cells-ranges-rows-or-columns-on-a-worksheet-23f64223-2b6b-453a-8688-248355f10fa9) but it isn't helping at all, and I don't why my question isn't answered with Google.

Basically, suppose I filtered out what I need from the Spreadsheet. My `C` column has everything I need, but I need to move them. And the formula is very simple. I basically need to move `C#` *All the filtered C's with the number*, and move them to `E#-1` *2 columns to the right, and up 1*.

But the issue is
* When I select C, it also selects the ones that I don't want
* I don't know what formula exists that can solve it

Comment: What do you mean `Move`? Formulas can't actually move anything. They can display the value of one cell in another, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you want to move the filtered results to column E, and have them move up 1 so for instance the value of cell C2 will move to cell E1? and do you want this to be relevant to the original cell in Column C or do you want all then filtered values moved to E1, E2, E3 and so on?

Comment: Yes, I want to move the filtered ones to column E and move them up 1 relevant to the original cell.